# Strange behaviour of images in RecyclerView

Tags: android, imageview, arrays, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I am using android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView to show simple items containing text and in some cases also images. Basically I followed the tutorial from here https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html and just changed the type of mDataset from String[] to JSONArray and the xml of the ViewHolder. My RecyclerView is located in a simple Fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

<!-- A RecyclerView with some commonly used attributes -->
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/my_hopps_recycler_view"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In this fragment I am loading all information from a webserver. After receiving the information I initialize the items in the RecyclerView. I use a LinearLayoutManager which is set in the onCreate method of my Fragment. After adding the Adapter, I call the setHasFixedSize(true) method on my RecyclerView. My Adapter class looks like this:

```
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import saruul.julian.MyFragment;
import saruul.julian.R;

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

/**
* Fragment holding the RecyclerView.
*/
private MyFragment myFragment;
/**
* The data to display.
*/
private JSONArray mDataset;

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView text;
    ImageView image;

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.my_view_text);
        image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.my_view_image);
    }
}

public MyAdapter(MyFragment callingFragment, JSONArray myDataset) {
    myFragment = callingFragment;
    mDataset = myDataset;
}

@Override
public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                               int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.my_view, parent, false);
    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}

// Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    try {
        JSONObject object = mDataset.getJSONObject(position);
        if ( object.has("image") ){
            if ( !hopp.getString("image").equals("") ){
                try {
                    byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJson(object.getString("image")), Base64.DEFAULT);
                    holder.image.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length));
                    holder.image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } catch ( Exception e ){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } 
        }
        if ( object.has("text") ){
            holder.text.setText(object.getString("text"));
        }
    } catch ( Exception e ){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

// Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataset.length();
}
}
```

And my xml for a view inside my RecyclerView:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/card_view"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/my_hopp_people_reached"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/my_hopp_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/my_hopp_text"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/my_hopp_delete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_discard"
        />

</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

So now here is my problem: Everything works fine. Text and picture are shown correctly in my RecyclerView. However if I reach the end of the list by scrolling down and scroll up again, pictures are shown in items which should not contain pictures. 
At the moment I have got nine items. The last two of them contain a picture. So I scroll down and just see text in the first seven items. Reaching the end of the list shows me two pictures as expected. But if I scroll up again those pictures appear in other items.

Scrolling up and down changes the pictures always in the same order:

- The first scrolling up (after being down once) creates a picture in the second item.
- Scrolling down creates a picture in the 7th item.
- Scrolling up creates a picture in the first item.
- Scrolling down creates nothing.
- Scrolling up creates a picture in the third item and the picture in the second item was overwritten with the other picture.
- Scrolling down creates a picture in the 6th item and lets the picture in  the 7th item disappear.
- And so on ...

I already discovered that the onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) method is called everytime an item appears again on the screen. I checked for the position and the given information in my mDataset. Everything works fine here: The position is right and the given information too. The text in all items does not change and is always shown correctly.
Does anyone have any kind of this problem and knows some solution?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I think you need to add an `else` clause to your `if ( object.has("image") )` statement in the `onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position)` method, setting the image to null:

```
holder.image.setImageDrawable(null);
```

I think [the documentation for onBindViewHolder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#onBindViewHolder(VH,%20int)) describe it best why this is necessary:

> Called by RecyclerView to display the data at the specified position. This method should update the contents of the itemView to reflect the item at the given position.

You should always assume that the ViewHolder passed in needed to be completely updated :)

Comment: This seems to do the trick ! I put an else clause to my if ( !hopp.getString("image").equals("") ) statement because there will be always an image field in my JSONObjects. I tried the same thing but used holder.image.setImageBitmap(null) which obviously did not work or I put it also in the wrong if statement. It does not matter because you saved my day. :)

Comment: Thanks. I modified to `holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);`

Answer (score 14):

Not sure if people still have issues with this, but the if statement did not work for me. What did work for me is this:

Using an override on this method in the adapter

```
@Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }
```

followed by calling the if statement based on this for the image itself within the onBindViewHolder, like so:

```
int pos = getItemViewType(position);
            if(theList.get(pos).getPicture() == null) {

                holder.picture.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {

                Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.robot).into(holder.picture);
            }
```

I am using Picasso but it should work with any other else situation. Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Adding getItemViewType fixed my problem!

Comment: This cannot be considered as a solution. You basically tell `RecyclerView` do not recycle at all.

Answer (score 3):

Based on @Lion789's answer.
I'm using Google's [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html) for image and json loading.

This allows us to retrieve the position on the view that's going to be recycled later.

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

When making the request, set the position as the TAG

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ItemHolder holder, int position) {
        ImageRequest thumbnailRequest = new ImageRequest(url,
                new Response.Listener<Bitmap>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Bitmap response) {                          
                        holder.itemThumbnail.setImageBitmap(response);
                    }
                },[...]);

        thumbnailRequest.setTag(String.valueOf(position)); //setting the TAG
        mQueue.addToRequestQueue(thumbnailRequest);
}
```

And when the view is being recycled we'll cancel the request, and remove the current image

```
@Override
public void onViewRecycled(ItemHolder holder) {
    super.onViewRecycled(holder);
    mQueue.cancelAll(String.valueOf(holder.getItemViewType()));
    holder.itemThumbnail.setImageDrawable(null);
}
```

Volley garanties that canceled requests won't be delivered.

Comment: wouldnt this then call the images everytime the view comes back into view?

Comment: Yes, but since Volley caches everything, the image would already be in memory